# Can I use StructureMap to return all implementations of a generic interface for a specific type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, structuremap

I have a generic interface, IValidator.  I want to be able to use StructureMap to retrieve a list of all classes that implement IValidator for a given type T. For example,

```
var PersonValidators = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IValidator<Person>>();
var AddressValidators = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IValidator<Address>>();
```

I know how to retrieve ALL classes that implement IValidator but I need to filter it by the type of the type parameter.

Can anyone give me any guidance or suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will work exactly like your example. You just have to make sure the instances are registered with the container. One way is to scan for the types:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        scan.AddAllTypesOf<IValidator<Person>>();
        scan.AddAllTypesOf<IValidator<Address>>();
    });
});

var PersonValidators = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IValidator<Person>>();
```